# Import Facebook Contacts to my application using Angular

Tags: angularjs, facebook, import, contacts

I am creating an application and using angular as my js framework.i wanted to import the contacts of  facebook user(who will provide his email and password) to his account on my application. How i can do that using angular..i have done an extensive RnD and found almost nothing about about it.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this endpoint to get friends: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/friends

Keep in mind that you can only get friends who authorized your App too, and you can´t get the email of friends either. All friend permissions are gone as you can read in the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Meaning, you can only get data of users who authorized your App.

Edit: About inviting friends, please read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#friend_invite

Inviting friends (to become friends) is not possible at all, btw.

Comment: if we cant get the email of my friends how i can send them invitation email..the purpose to import contacts is to send them invitation..

Comment: you don´t do that by email, that would be spam anyway.

Comment: one possibility to invite friends: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Comment: both links you provided seems to be irrelevant..Because  there is no help regarding send invitations to my friends list from my social website.

Comment: the send dialog is very well known to be used for that.

Comment: there are only apprequests in addition, but those are for games only

Comment: i dont think that it works in case of sending invitation from my social site.

Comment: i added an important link about inviting in my answer. it explains everything you need to know about inviting.

Comment: it is something already on facebook..i have to invite from other platform.

Comment: did u ever send an invitation on skype to facebook friends???it sends them friend request invitation..while in case of send dialogue we are sending a url.sorry i forgot to say thanks to u for the time u r giving me to sort out this issue

Comment: so you want to send a "friend request"? that´s not possible at all with the api.

Comment: no, of course not. you can only get data of users who authorized your app. everything else would be a privacy issue.